# Timer resets after 60 seconds

Tags: c#, timer

Below is the code that I'm attempting to use as an elapsed timer on a desktop task timer that we're building. Right now when this runs it only counts to 60 seconds and then resets and doesn't ever add to the minutes.

```
//tick timer that checks to see how long the agent has been sitting in the misc timer status, reminds them after 5 mintues to ensure correct status is used
private void statusTime_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    counter++;
    //The timespan will handle the push from the elapsed time in seconds to the label so we can update the user
    //This shouldn't require a background worker since it's a fairly small app and nothing is resource heavy

    var timespan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(actualTimer.Elapsed.Seconds);

    //convert the time in seconds to the format requested by the user
    displaycounter.Text=("Elapsed Time in " + statusName+" "+ timespan.ToString(@"mm\:ss"));

    //pull the thread into updating the UI
    Application.DoEvents();

}
```

Comment: Can you share how timer is initialized?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Quick Fix**

I believe the problem is that you are using `Seconds` which is 0-59. You want to use `TotalSeconds` with your existing code:

```
var timespan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(actualTimer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
```

---

**Comments**

However, this doesn't make a lot of sense as you could just use the `TimeSpan` object directly:

```
var timespan = actualTimer.Elapsed;
```

Also, I can't see all your application, but I would expect you do not need to call `Application.DoEvents();`. As the UI should update automatically when it has the chance... if it doesn't then you want to look at moving whatever code is blocking the UI to a different thread.

---

**Recommendation**

With all that said, I would recommend you don't use a timer to track elapsed time at all. Timers can lose accuracy over time. The best approach is to store the current system time when you start the process, then when you need to display the 'timer' do an on-demand calculation at that point.

A very simple example to help explain what I mean:

```
DateTime start;

void StartTimer()
{
    start = DateTime.Now;
}

void UpdateDisplay()
{
    var timespan = DateTime.Now.Subtract(start);
    displaycounter.Text = "Elapsed Time in " + statusName + " " + timespan.ToString(@"mm\:ss"));
}
```

You could then use a timer to call your `UpdateDisplay` method at regular intervals:

```
void statusTime_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateDisplay();
}
```